# Vuforia jewellery try out without marker

Tags: unity, augmented-reality, vuforia

I need to create a virtual jewellery try out in unity 3d + vuforia. I have done it with  marker as a target but now i need to do it without marker. Is there any way we can track live objects using userdefined targets i mean face , neck ,arm, finger using vuforia.

I have done a lot of research but didnt got anything useful.

Comment: Vuforia is all about markers. If you want to track something you need a marker.

Comment: @DH. cant we do it with user defined targets?

Comment: Would it be an option to use a specialized device like a Kinect, or do you need this to work with more common phone/tablet/laptop/desktop cameras?

Comment: @DMGregory yeah i need to do it on android/ios not only windows so i  cant use kinect

Comment: [Vuforia does include support for user-defined image targets](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Developer-for-User-Defined-Targets-in-Unity), but I don't see support for face/hand/body tracking. The place to go for confirmation would be Vuforia's product support forum. There are other middleware solutions folks use for this kind of problem, including OpenCV, but recommending particular technologies is outside StackExchange's scope.